# С чего начать программировать блокчейн?

Tags: blockchain, криптовалюта, блокчейн

Подскажите, с чего начать программирование блокчейн технологий с нуля?
Как создать криптовалюту и переслать её?
Какие примеры вы использовали?

Comment: С досконального изучения криптографии.

Comment: @post_zeew а по-подробнее можно пожалуйста? Ведь книг много. Может что-то особое посоветуете, с чего начать?

Comment: Наверное с запроса `github blockchain` и изучения того, что уже сделано